# Perform tasks in the correct order in Scala and Akka without blocking

Tags: multithreading, scala, akka, nonblocking, akka-http

I have microservice that works with Couchbase. My service must ask Couchbase how many documents I have with the current id: if the number is low, I create another document.

My problem is that this is non-blocking: if I have a lot of requests when I first create a document, a second request *also* shows that the number of documents and is low (because first don't create yet document), so *another* new document is created.

To resolve this issue I created an actor system in akka with one actor per id, blocking (with Await) until the first is finished.  This gives the order that I want.  Is there a better way to do this?

But I have the issue when I add Kafka producer to this 'Await' Future, when kafka is down this future is blocking so long that I have timeout for Await. I put this producer in Future, but after this I don't have many threads in my Executor Context.

Comment: Clarified wording; fixed grammar errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Circuit Breaker here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/common/circuitbreaker.html

I usually use this when I'm doing external service calls where that service has a tendency to be unavailable.

Comment: Circuit Breake is not for my question. I need right order in this situation, not to ask unless is ok